# Delete GridView Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to delete a row in the GridView by having a input type="image" and a ID of that row associated to the image so if you click on that image it will call a function in asp.net and delete that record out of Database based on that ID and reload that grid.
What the best way to approach this? Thanks for your help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdHouses" runat="server"
        CssClass="gridview"
        RowStyle-CssClass="gridview_itm"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview_aitm"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview_hdr" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="image" name="imgDelete" class="listViewTdToolsS1" src="../App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/delete_inline.gif" alt="rem" style="height:12px;width:12px;border-width:0px;" value=""
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>">
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Name_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="NAME" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Name_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Name")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Description_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="DESCRIPTION" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Description_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" CausesValidation="false" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Description")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Add dataKeyNames= "Id" in gridview

Answer (score 0):

A command button:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
 <ItemTemplate>        
         <asp:ImageButton runat="server"  
             CommandName='DeleteItem'
             CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'
             CssClass="listViewTdToolsS1"
             ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/delete_inline.gif"
             Tooltip="rem"
 </ItemTemplate>     
</asp>
```

Handle the GridView OnItemCommand event:

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="DeleteItem")
    {
         var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
         // delete the object from database
         Database.DeleteObject(id);
         // rebind the gridview
         grdHouses.DataSource = DataBase.GetItems();
          grdHouses.DataBind();
    }
  }
```

Since the DataSource is set in code behind, I recommend to use *DeleteItem* or something else instead of *Delete* as a command name.

Comment: Hey Thank for your help but now I am getting an error: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: I changed a bit my answer, maybe that was. You don't need the following anymore <input type="image" name="imgDelete".

Answer (score 0):

First Add DataKeyName in your grid-view like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdHouses" runat="server"
    CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="ID"
    RowStyle-CssClass="gridview_itm"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview_aitm"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview_hdr" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdeleting="grdHouses_RowDeleting">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Name_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="NAME" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Name_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("Name")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Description_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="DESCRIPTION" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" CausesValidation="false" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Description_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" CausesValidation="false" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("Description")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
<ItemTemplate>
    <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB" runat="Server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete">    </asp:LinkButton>
     </span>
 </ItemTemplate>

 </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then on code behind use RowDeleting of gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete FROM Table Name where ID='" + id + "'";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();

        }
    }        
}
```